# Security::hash() does not return the same hash

Tags: php, linux, cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have done a lot of changes in my new website.

I just noticed that Security::hash('password', null, true) does not return the same thing as the previou version.

I upgrade cake from 2.3.1 to 2.3.9 but I am using **the same** `'Security.salt'` and `'Security.cipherSeed'` values.

What can i check?

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I read in CahePHP 2.3.5 changelog that you should not use Security.cipher because it is deprecated. https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/commit/06e7ba6

Try to experiment with other hash() parametrs than hash('password', null, true), test the examples from docs: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/security.html#Security::hash